# Surefire does not exclude JUnit 5 tests marked with @Tag

Tags: java, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 test with two test methods. One is annotated with the tag "slow" and the other with the tag "fast". I have also configured the SureFire plugin with excludeTags in that way that it should ignore the test with the "slow" tag.

I would expect that with this setup only the test with the "fast" tag would be executed but in my case both are. It seems that the @Tag annotations have no effect at all.

Here is the test class:

```
package junit5;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TaggingTest {

    @Tag("fast")
    @Test
    void fast() {
        System.out.println("*** fast ***");
    }

    @Tag("slow")
    @Test
    void slow() {
        System.out.println("*** slow ***");
    }

}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>junit5</groupId>
    <artifactId>tagging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <excludeTags>slow</excludeTags>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I run mvn test I've got this output:

```
> mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tagging 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tagging ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tagging ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tagging ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/olaf.prins/temp/junit-tagging/tagging/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tagging ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/olaf.prins/temp/junit-tagging/tagging/target/test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ tagging ---

-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running junit5.TaggingTest
*** fast ***
*** slow ***
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.049 sec - in junit5.TaggingTest

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.800 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-15T16:36:14+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/512M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see both test cases have been run.

As I understand the documentation I've setup up everything correctly. What do I miss?

Comment: The maven-surefire-plugin seems to have a bug when run using JDK 9: It does not pass properties to Surefire providers. I will open an issue with them. In the meantime, can you try to run with JDK 8?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp I still wonder(after the accepted answer), how did java 9 come into the picture here?

Comment: Both target and source in the above pom are set to "9". I debugged the maven-surefire-plugin and found the root cause as described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1445. And this only happens on JDK 9 where, apparently, the implementation of `Properties` has changed.

Comment: It seems I faced the same issue, but using jdk8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by a bug in the maven-surefire-plugin when it runs on JDK 9: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1445

Comment: Looks like an incidence of the classic fragile base class problem ;-)